# Set up my form( leave form) need to automate a few things

Tags: python, django

So i set up my app for LEAVE MANAGEMENT. I was Wondering however is there a way i can automate the days. For example if sick leave==5days, when the user selects sick leave, the system automatically tells them how many days they have. They can be able to take all days, less but not more than the assigned days.
And when the user selects when they want to start their leave, then the end date is automatically filled excluding weekends.
Thank you i know it is a lot but i will gladly appreciate some help.

```
SICK = 'sick'
CASUAL = 'casual'
EMERGENCY = 'emergency'
STUDY = 'study'
MATERNITY = 'maternity'

LEAVE_TYPE = (
(SICK, 'Sick Leave'),
(CASUAL, 'Casual Leave'),
(EMERGENCY, 'Emergency Leave'),
(STUDY, 'Study Leave'),
(MATERNITY, 'Maternity Leave'),
)

class Leave(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
startdate = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('Start Date'),help_text='leave start date is on ..',null=True,blank=False)
enddate = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('End Date'),help_text='coming back on ...',null=True,blank=False)
leavetype = models.CharField(choices=LEAVE_TYPE,max_length=25,default=SICK,null=True,blank=False)
reason = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Reason for Leave'),max_length=255,help_text='add additional information for leave',null=True,blank=True)
defaultdays = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_('Leave days per year counter'),default=DAYS,null=True,blank=True)



status = models.CharField(max_length=12,default='pending') #pending,approved,rejected,cancelled
is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False) #hide

updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question leaves out some info, but I'm guessing you are displaying a form, on which the user will choose a leave type from a choicefield.  After they make that selection, if they choose sick leave, you want to update a field on the form to show the amount of sick days they have available.  Does that sound right?  If so, then you can put a [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/) listener like

```
$("#id_leavetype").change(function () { ...
```

(in the html file) on the choicefield and use, for example, AJAX, to pass the id of the leave choice to a function in your views.py which will return the data or a string to populate your form field with.  If you haven't used AJAX, there's a good intro to it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).  The function will return the data to the html using, for example,

```
return JsonResponse(data)
```

which you can read about in the django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects).

If I missed the point of your question, add some info about the form, template, view and so on.